# .asmx Web Service Documentation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'd like my summary, param info, returns info, etc (listed below) to show up on the standard help page that .net generates for .asmx web services.

```
/// <summary>
/// Brief description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fakeParamOne">Fake Param One Description</param>
/// <returns>Bool representing foo</returns>
```

The only thing that I've tried that affected the auto-generated help page in any way was this:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Does awesome things.")]
```

I'm sure I'm missing something VERY simple (or it's not possible to do what I want). Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no automatic way to do what you're asking. In fact, the help page has been abandoned in WCF, as it was of very limited utility.

Comment: "the help page has been abandoned in WCF, as it was of very limited utility"? BEG YOUR PARDON??? You're kidding me!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like @John Saunders comment mentioned there's not really an automatic way to use the XML method comments to show up in the WSDL Help, but there are a couple of alternatives to get what you're looking for.

**WebMethod Description attribute can be set to be formatted HTML**

Here's an example:

```
const string someWebMethodDescription = @"
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Summary:</td><td>[My Summary]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Parameters:</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fakeParam:</td><td>[My Fake Param Description]</td>
    </tr>
</table>";

[WebMethod(Description=someWebMethodDescription)]
public List<string> SomeWebMethod
```

Where the result is:

[image: Web Method with Custom HTML Description]

**Alternatively, to create a custom WSDL Help Page**

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <webServices>
         <wsdlHelpGenerator href="docs/HelpPage.aspx"/>
      </webServices>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

check this codeproject post for details on making your own HelpPage:

[Improving the ASP.NET Webservice Help Generator to Reflect Inheritance - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xsltwsdlhelp.aspx)