# Document ASMX webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I'm developing a web service to publish for different users consume.

To smooth their work I want to document all my web methods, and their input/output objects, just like on the image below (its a sample that i saw on web).

[image]

I just tried to use WebMethodAttribute's to decorate my methods, but the only thing I achieved was the method description.

I tried to use WCFExtras but does not fit in my project because its not a WCF service :/

I ask: is there any kind of tool to do this kind of job? Does anyone knows any .NET property or framework to use?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you using ASMX web services for new development? WCF should be used for all new development.

Comment: I started developing a WCF service, but a client told to develop a ASMX webservice... not my idea :/

Comment: 2 years later, and I can direct you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390806/asmx-web-service-documentation

Answer (score 0):

I've been happy with a combination of [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) and standard [C# XML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Basically, you comment the methods as you normally do (type `///` right before the type or method name to generate the comment skeleton).  Then, you enable [enable XML documentation output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7%28VS.71%29.aspx) on the project.  Finally, you use a tool (for example, Sandcastle) to consume the generated XML file to build a help file/web site.

In Sandcastle's case, it generates a CHM.  I personally like viewing the API as a CHM file.  There are other tools to make this a Web site.

Comment: The sample at the image above, I typed the webservice address http://machine/webservice.asmx and the all methods information is showed like that... is there any tool that allow me to do that?

Comment: I question the value of putting your docs in the same location as your service. Different security requirements, for one thing.